# python fabric run function once for all servers

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

we have a deploy script that has 5 servers, we want to run the script and notify us only once even though it runs for 5 servers.

The example code:

env.hosts = ['web1', 'web2', 'web3', 'web4', 'web5']

```
def notify():
    sendNotify()

@task
def deploy():
    sendNotify()
    deploy stuff
    deploy stuff
    deploy stuff
    deploy stuff
```

I want that notify will be called only once, but because there are 5 servers it is called 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `@runs_once` decorator on `notify`.

See: http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.4/api/core/decorators.html#fabric.decorators.runs_once